# How can I create a CRUD API using Node.js, Express.js, and MongoDB?

Tags: api, backend

How to make an API crud method with nodejs expressjs mongodb?
How to make an API crud method with nodejs expressjs mongodb?
How to make an API crud method with nodejs expressjs mongodb?

please help me with making an api.i have a problem that i cant solve by myself.ill be glad if you will help me :)